# Date as a superscipt format in iPhone

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

i want to display the Date in iPhone through programming like this

1st February 2013

means as a superscipt "st"

is it possible?

Comment: i think you do can`t do directly but we can implement with the help of webview

Answer (score 1):

The **class** you are looking for is `NSAttributeString` and the **Attribute** you are looking for is `NSSuperscriptAttributeName`.

Reference: [Apple Docs Attributed Strings](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AttributedStrings/Articles/standardAttributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004903-SW2)

Comment: Note that this is only available from iOS6 onwards.

Comment: I'm not sure if they support superscript but OHAttributedLabel I believe was the popular choice before iOS6. If you still need an example with NSAttributeString let me know https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel/tree/master/OHAttributedLabel/Source